# How to make editable & non editable rows with Backgrid.js in a single grid

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

I would like to render a grid with editable & non editable rows based on condition.  I'm able to do achive setting color to differentiate this, but making it non editable for deleted records will be more useful.  expecting good solutions.

```
var DeletedRow = Backgrid.Row.extend({
render: function () {
DeletedRow.__super__.render.apply(this, arguments);
if (!_.isUndefined(this.model.get("action")) && this.model.get("action") == "D") {
this.el.bgColor = "#C0C0C0";
}
return this;
}
});
```

Comment: How do you mark a model as deleted now that you are not actually removing it from the collection?

Comment: My requirement is not to delete the record.  I only need to disable the row based on "action" attribute.  I've achieved it by this way                                                     (this.$el.find("td[class=actionDescription]")).parent().find("*").unbind();
this.$el.click(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has bee resolved.

```
    var DeletedRow = Backgrid.Row.extend({
    render: function () {
    DeletedRow.__super__.render.apply(this, arguments);
    if (!_.isUndefined(this.model.get("action")) && this.model.get("action") == "D") {
    (this.$el.find("td[class=actionDescription]")).parent().find("*").unbind();
    this.$el.click(false);
    }
    return this;
    }
    });
```